# What is the right way to wire together 2 javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, passive-view

I'm currently facing a conundrum: What is the right way to wire together 2 javascript objects?

Imagine an application like a text editor with several different files.  I have some HTML page that represents the view for the notebook. I have a file notebook.js that contains class definitions for NotebookController and Notebook View.

NotebookControler object responsible for performing business logic on the Notebook like "Save Notebook," "Load Notebook," "New Notebook."  NotebookView is responsible for managing the HTML that is used for presentation.  It does low level stuff like "get/set notebook body" "get/set notebook name." It also listens for DOM events (onClick) and fires business events (saveNotebook). This is my attempt at the Passive View pattern.

I want my javascript client-side code to be object-oriented, separated concerns, and unit-testable.  I want to test NotebookController with a mock NotebookView and vice versa.  This means that I can't just instantiate a NotebookView inside the NotebookController.  So do I

- Put some logic in my notebook.js that wires the 2 together
- Have a global function in my application that knows to instantiate one of each and wire them together
- Use Dependency Injection, either a home-grown one or something like SquirrelIoc

In Java, the choice is a natural one: use Spring.  But that doesn't seem very JavaScript-y. What's the right thing to do?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can you not achieve testability by just making sure you're using aggregation instead of composition?

Comment: That's the idea.  But the question really is what's the right way to wire up that aggregation of objects?

Answer (score 3):

Dependency injection is probably your best bet. Compared to Java, some aspects of this are easier to do in JS code, since you can pass an object full of callbacks into your NotebookController. Other aspects are harder, because you don't have the static code analysis to formalize the interface between them.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the insight.  I ended up writing a simple JavaScript dependency injection utility.  After debating for a while and your comments, it occured to me that DI was really the right answer because:

1. It totally separated the concerns of wiring from the business logic while keeping the wiring logic close to the things being wired.
2. It allowed me to generically provide a "you're all wired up" callback on my objects so that I could do a 3 phase initialization: instantiate everything, wire it all up, call everyone's callbacks and tell them they're wired.
3. It was easy to check for dependency missing problems.

So here's the DI utility:

```
var Dependency = function(_name, _instance, _dependencyMap) {
    this.name = _name;
    this.instance = _instance;
    this.dependencyMap = _dependencyMap;
}

Dependency.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.name;
}

CONCORD.dependencyinjection = {};

CONCORD.dependencyinjection.Context = function() {
    this.registry = {};
}

CONCORD.dependencyinjection.Context.prototype = {
    register : function(name, instance, dependencyMap) {
        this.registry[name] = new Dependency(name, instance, dependencyMap);
    }, 
    get : function(name) {
        var dependency = this.registry[name];
        return dependency != null ? dependency.instance : null;
    },

    init : function() {
        YAHOO.log("Initializing Dependency Injection","info","CONCORD.dependencyinjection.Context");
        var registryKey;
        var dependencyKey;
        var dependency;
        var afterDependenciesSet = [];
        for (registryKey in this.registry) {
            dependency = this.registry[registryKey];
            YAHOO.log("Initializing " + dependency.name,"debug","CONCORD.dependencyinjection.Context");

            for(dependencyKey in dependency.dependencyMap) {
                var name = dependency.dependencyMap[dependencyKey];
                var instance = this.get(name);
                if(instance == null) {
                    throw "Unsatisfied Dependency: "+dependency+"."+dependencyKey+" could not find instance for "+name;
                }
                dependency.instance[dependencyKey] = instance; 
            }

            if(typeof dependency.instance['afterDependenciesSet'] != 'undefined') {
                afterDependenciesSet.push(dependency);
            }
        }

        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < afterDependenciesSet.length; i++) {
            afterDependenciesSet[i].instance.afterDependenciesSet();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say, just wire them together:

```
function wireTogether() {
  var v = new View();
  var c = new Controller();
  c.setView(v);
}
```

But then of course another question raises - how do you test the wireTogether() function?

Luckily, JavaScript is a really dynamic language, so you can just assign new values to View and Controller:

```
var ok = false;

View.prototype.isOurMock = true;
Controller.prototype.setView = function(v) {
  ok = v.isOurMock;
}

wireTogether();

alert( ok ? "Test passed" : "Test failed" );
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a inversion of control library for javascript, I'm pretty happy with it.  https://github.com/fschwiet/jsfioc.  It also supports events, so if you want to have a startup event thats fine.  It could use more documentation...

http://github.com/fschwiet/jsfioc

Another (newer?) option, which has better documentation and support, is requireJS (http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

There is also a framework for dependency injection for JavaScript: https://github.com/briancavalier/wire

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to take a stab at this, but it will be a little difficult without seeing any actual code.  Personally, I've never seen anybody do such a specific attempt at (M)VC with JavaScript or IoC for that matter.

First of all, what are you going to test with?  If you haven't already, check out the [YUI Test video](http://video.yahoo.com/watch/3737228/10267335) which has some good info on unit testing with javascript.

Secondly, when you say "the best way to wire up that aggregation" I would probably just do it as a setter w/the controller

```
// Production
var cont = new NotebookController();
cont.setView( new NotebookView() );

// Testing the View
var cont = new NotebookController();
cont.setView( new MockNotebookView() );

// Testing the Controller
var cont = new MockNotebookController();
cont.setView( new NotebookView() );

// Testing both
var cont = new MockNotebookController();
cont.setView( new MockNotebookView() );
```

But this makes some big assumption on how you've designed your controller and view objects already.